# html 5 canvas drawing is slow!

Tags: html, canvas, draw

I am making a web application which is similar to paint. The problem that I am facing right now is that my drawing algorithm is awfully slow. Basically what I am doing is drawing a straight line between successive pixels that have been recorded with the mousemove event.

Is there a smarter/(less expensive) way to draw user created lines and curves using html 5 canvas?

EDIT:
It is incredibly slow only when I am redrawing the strokes that were already on the canvas.

Comment: How do you save the color for every pixel and how do you repaint the canvas?

Comment: Can we see your code? As described you code should be incredibly fast, but you are probably saving too much data or else redoing too much work.

Comment: I have a private variable called rgba, and I set context.strokeStyle = rgba

Comment: check the EDIT.. sorry I should have mentioned this

Comment: We won't be able to help you without any code. Please post your algorithm here. We also need to know your browser version, etc.

Comment: My _guess_ (since you will not give enough information to actually help you) is that you are probably accumulating more and more paths to draw every time the user moves the mouse. Are you calling `beginPath()` before each update? Are you clearing and re-drawing the whole canvas each update, or just invoking a new `stroke()` command?

Comment: @fogy: Please add your code. Or rather a minimal example. It is impossible to tell if there is a smart*er* way to draw user created lines and curves using HTML 5 canvas when we don't know what your code is.

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do conceptually should be incredibly fast. Since you won't give us the code, here:

http://jsfiddle.net/mXrNk/1/

If this is faster, use it as a starting point.

Comment: Note that this suffers from horrible aliasing because you are re-drawing the same long path over-and-over-and-over for each mousemove event, instead of properly just drawing the delta. Here is a minimally-changed version that performs as it ought to: http://jsfiddle.net/mXrNk/2/

Comment: +1! I completely overlooked. Adept as always, Phrogz

Answer (score 1):

The slowness (what exactly is slow? Slow to load, or slow to render?) might be caused by the hardware acceleration in your browser. What's your browser/OS? I find that Safari 5 in OS X and IE9 in Windows 7 have the fastest draw rates because of their hardware acceleration. In Chrome, you'll have to turn it on in about:flags, and it is a bit finicky.

Comment: The only time that it is slow is when I want to redraw the strokes done by the user. For example, the user draws 50 lines on the canvas, I want to clear the Canvas and redraw all those 50 lines.